oneOf in protobuf descriptor due to optional fields
I have encountered strange protobuf-java behavior.
If I have a message with optional fields
message SearchRequest {
  optional string query = 1;
  optional int32 page_number = 2;
  optional int32 results_per_page = 3;
}

If I check the descriptor generated by protoc SearchRequest.getDescriptor().getOneofs() is not empty but contains all the fields
If I remove the optional, it works as expected.
To me, this is a bit scary as the fields definitely do not have oneOf semantics. Is it a bug or am I missing something?
Here is a reproducer. protobuf version is 3.25.3 but works the same in 4.27.2

Oneofs seem to be a bit of an afterthought in Google Protocol Buffers. If you are expecting to receive a oneof, but the sender actually sends more than one of the oneof's fields, the receive deserialiser will quite happily deserialise all of them, keeping the last one it gets.
I think that that's very odd behaviour... Oneof seems to mean something more like "keep the last optional field sent", rather than "being sent more than one field is an error".
So I suspect it's something related to this.
